# use calculation as the condition in loop

Tags: bash, for-loop

I've a script named `t.sh` as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

num=2
for i in {0..$((num-1))}; do
        echo 'aaa'
done

for i in {0..1}; do
        echo 'bbb'
done
```

The output of `./t.sh`:

```
aaa
bbb
bbb
```

I can't understand at all. `$((num-1))` equals to 1, so I think `aaa` should be printed twice, just like `bbb`, why it shows only once?

Comment: `..` requires the values to be literals, not variables or expressions.

Comment: You are getting `aaa` printed because `i` gets the literal value `{0..1}` not `1`.

Comment: Use the evil `eval`.